# Pushing an OSB12 configjar to a Nexus repository

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, nexus, osb

I'm using the configjar tool (shell script with a settings xml) to package an OSB 12 application into one config jar. This is done with Jenkins, so the build step is to execute a Linux shell script (which uses the configjar tool).
Ultimately the resulting config jar file should be in a Nexus repository. Can I do this with Jenkins, or is there a way to write the URL of the Nexus repository into the setting file for the configjar tool?
I was told I couldn't or shouldn't use the physical location (e.g. path/to/a/directory) of the Nexus repository but use the URL instead.
I couldn't get the mvn package command to work with the pom file although that would be a solution because I could write into the pom file to use the Nexus repository, I'm trying to solve that problem in a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could e.g. use the [Maven deploy plugin with the deploy-file goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) to upload the artifact. That would probably the easiest.

You can also use a REST API based upload with a shell script or Eclipse Aether Ant tasks in a Ant script.

Comment: Yeah that's what I do: bind the configjar execution to `package` and use the deploy plugin to push it to the remote repo on `deploy`.

Comment: I am not talking about doing that.. I am talking about using the deploy-file goal which works independently of the pom file and any related build process.

Comment: Well you can force the G/A/V settings via command-line if you need to, but   if you can get the configjar working with maven at all, it's a really small step to then hook it into the standard lifecycle. Perhaps edit your question to include your pom?

Comment: Thanks @Manfred Moser, I'm actualloy trying to use the distributionManagement tag in the pom file. That lets me specify the repo I'd like to upload my application to. I fixed my previous problem, so the package command works, only the deploy fails with Destination unreachable, No available router to destination. Caused by: t3://localhost:7001: Destination 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 7001. As far as I know that's the Weblogic server. But where is the reference to that? Surely not in my pom or the settings.xml

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I'm using the oracle servicebus plugin (as this is an OSB12c application) and this plugin is using some incorrect default values for the weblogic server. However, I don't need to have it deployed on the weblogic server, I just need the whole thing packaged as a config jar and then be uploaded to a Nexus repo. @Trent Bartlem, is this what you are trying to suggest? I could just do the configjar packaging with the package command, then use the deploy plugin?

Comment: If you add the distribution mgt and the Maven is actually building the jar and you can mvn deploy, it should work.

Comment: OK, so if you just want it packaged up, then the osb plugin should trigger when you run `mvn package`. You can then do the `deploy:deploy-file` goal and push the changes out.

Comment: Thanks, @Trent Bartlem, now that's exactly what I'm doing. Now I got error 400, Bad Request. That's supposed to happen with wrong credentials but deploying the other files to Nexus (without the config jar) worked with the deploy goal, so the credential setting in the settings.xml should be right.

Comment: What's `mvn -X deploy:deploy-file ...` say?

Comment: @Trent Bartlem: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project osbbuild: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.mycompany:osbbuild:jar:1.0.0-20151104.120540-1 from/to mycomopany-snapshots (http://path/to/repositories): Failed to transfer file: http://path/to/repositories/mycompany/osbbuild/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/osbbuild-1.0.0-20151104.120540-1.jar. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.

Comment: OK, well Bad Request means the repo has rejected the upload. Two reasons could be trying to deploy a snapshot to a non-snapshot repo (check the `distributionManagement` section of your pom), or you're trying to upload the same file twice in the same mvn execution, or too soon after the last upload.

Comment: @Trent Bartlem: Of course. It was poking my eyes out. I only kept checking the occurrences of the url in the various files (pom and setings) instead of taking a look at the parameters of the actual maven command I was issuing. Anyway, it's kinda redundant to have to supply the repo url as an id and a url in the deploy parameters, this was the root of my problem. So I was supplying the wrong url in the Durl param. Works now! Thanks!